# 'C' program design for Linux/Win64 console app; use fork() or Windows equivalent?

Tags: c, asynchronous, keyboard

The question is: should I use fork() on Linux and CreateProcess etc. on Windows to allow keyboard input to be collected concurrently with other processing? Or is there a better way? I want a clean design that allows asynch input from the keyboard, regardless of whether the main code is busy processing, or waiting for data from a socket.

As far as I can see, my current code will always wait for input:

```
fgets(keyb_text, sizeof(keyb_text), stdin);
```

As I understand it, Windows only allows use of select() with sockets. I can't use it with stdin.

Background: I'm writing a portable 'bytecode' machine, as an exercise to help me learn more 'C'. It will be for Linux, Windows and possibly others. But the issue would be the same for writing a simple Telnet client--I may want to type something while data is arriving.

And I lack design experience on PC hardware. I'd have taken a very different approach on MVS last century :-)

fgets(keyb_text, sizeof(keyb_text), stdin);

I was expecting/hoping to be able to tell whether input is available from keyboard, but stackoverflow is full of the same question.

Comment: Both Linux (and other POSIX systems like macOS) and Windows have functions to do unbuffered and direct I/O with the terminals. For POSIX systems it's usually done with [termios](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/termios.3.html) functions and attributes. Then you can use `read` or `select`/`poll` to poll the `STDIN_FILENO` to check when input is available and read that. [The Windows console functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-functions) give similar abilities.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean by collecting keyboard input, since `fgets` and other standard functions require a termination with new line or EOF, so they are already unsuitable. It would seem that creating second process is always the wrong solution also, what you need is multi-threading. Use OS-specific API to collect key presses and do so in a separate thread. Some *nix-like compilers support pthreads in Windows, or otherwise you'll have to use CreateThread in Windows a pthreads in Linux.

Comment: @Lundin "collecting keyboard input" may be want to do bad something.

Comment: @Tom I recall writing a Windows program back in the days where everything you typed no matter what was replaced by various song lyrics :) I don't think that's possible any longer, they've tightened up "low level hooks".

Comment: @Lundin It sounds good that cracker can not do bad something.

Comment: I'm using CreateThread() in Win64 now and it works fine.

@Someprogrammerdude thanks for the pointer. I'll also be using some of the Windows console functions and I'm already writing some OS-specific code. It will help with my other (editor/IDE) project as well.

Comment: @Lundin Thanks. my example code with a get function was a bad choice--I'd tried just about every stdio function I could find and that was the last. I'm using CreateThread in win64--I only mentioned CreateProcess() because I'd just read advice that it can also create a thread, but seems to be bogus. CreateThread() is working fine.